# Model external NPT thread in solidworks using stud wizard

Tags: solidworks

I would like to know if it is possible to model external NPT threads in SolidWorks using the new stud wizard feature. I am using SW 2022 version. I tried to attempt, but all I am getting is NPSM threads instead of NPT. Since I am a newbie, I have limited working experience in this.